# PHPMailer using AddStringAttachment with AddAttachment

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a form that generates a PDF from the user inputs, As well as a file upload option.

So the user can upload a file or not and I use `AddAttachment` for this part, And `AddStringAttachment`for the generated PDF.

Here is my code:

```
//PDF
$pdf = $dompdf->output();    

//Configuration
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet  = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Host     = 'localhost';
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;

//Email details
$mail->From     = 'email@email.com'; 
$mail->FromName = 'My email'; 
$mail->Subject  = 'You have a new email';
$mail->Body     = 'Hi there, You have a new message.<br>';
$mail->AltBody  = 'Hi there, You have a new message.';

//Loop through recipients
$recipients = ['email1@email.com', 'email2@email.com'];

foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
    $mail->addAddress($recipient);
    $mail->AddStringAttachment($pdf, 'name.pdf'); 
    if (!empty($_FILES['upload']['tmp_path'])) {
        $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['upload']['tmp_path'], 'upload.pdf');    
    }

    if ( !$mail->Send() ) {
        echo 'Not sent';     
    } else {
        echo 'Sent';
    }

    // Clear all addresses and attachments for next loop
    $mail->clearAddresses();
    $mail->clearAttachments();
}
```

The issue is that when I upload a file, I receive 2 emails:
1- With the attachment and generated PDF (Which is expected)
2- With only the generated pdf. But the content is messed and looks wrong.

When I don't upload a file, I get only 1 email.

I tried to send to 1 email only and it's the same.

Comment: Why are you adding the attachments in the loop at all?

Comment: @miken32 Because attachments would be cleared at the end of each loop. I'm not sure how this part works `$mail->clearAddresses();
    $mail->clearAttachments();`

Comment: But you're just adding the same attachments over and over again.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks

Comment: There is too much information missing from your question to be sure, but it appears you have multiple issues.  I don't know if I missed this before or you updated the question, but why do you have addStringAttachment AND addAttachment.   You also have at least 6 variables that we have no idea about, as to what they may or may not contain ($recipients, $pdf, $filename, $path, $report, $attach)

Comment: You should only be using AddStringAttachment if you have some data that is already in a PHP string variable.  If you are using that, you also need to make sure that the variable is base64 encoded when you pass it, again assuming that you are intentionally using that function, which you certainly are calling.

Comment: `$pdf ` is a string coming from `Dompdf``$pdf = $dompdf->output();`. `$recipients` array of emails `$recipients = ['email1@email.com', 'email2@email.com'];`. `$filename` looks like `jon_doe_11-30-2021.pdf`

Comment: `$path` is the `tmp_path` from the uploaded file. `$report` is the name of the uploaded file

Comment: This is no longer answering a question, but rather it's debugging.  You have to check your assumptions.  The big assumption you have right now is that the uploaded file is valid.  I would check that assumption.  Typically you would first use  [move-uploaded-file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) possibly also doing a check on the file, then attach it.  Check that the form is using enctype="multipart/form-data".  Check the file itself.

Comment: I'd say the fundamental thing here is that your script is being run twice, once with user input and once without, and you have no mechanism to distinguish the two. This is a common enough problem that there is [a PHPMailer wiki article about it](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Diagnosing-email-sending-twice-(or-more)) and how to diagnose it. You're also failing to validate uploads, which is potentially dangerous. Take a look at [the PHPMailer file upload example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) for how to do that right.

Answer (score 1):

**If this works please do not mark this as the answer it goes to Gview, I just showed the code and fixed a resources problem.**

While Gview's answer should fix the problem you really should not be doing the attachment adding and removing inside the loop

This is the full code version using the fix that gview posted and not wasting CPU resources attaching and removing your PDF attachment needlessly. as miken32 has said in comments.

```php
//Configuration
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet  = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Host     = 'localhost';
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;

//Email details
$mail->From     = 'email@email.com'; 
$mail->FromName = 'My email'; 
$mail->Subject  = 'You have a new email';
$mail->Body     = 'Hi there, You have a new message.<br>';
$mail->AltBody  = 'Hi there, You have a new message.';

//Loop through recipients
$mail->AddStringAttachment($pdf, $filename); 
if (!empty($attach)) {
    $mail->AddAttachment($path, $report);    
}

foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
    $mail->addAddress($recipient);

    if ( !$mail->Send() ) {
        echo 'Not sent';     
    } else {
        echo 'Sent';
    }

    // Clear all addresses and attachments for next loop
    $mail->clearAllRecipients();
}

$mail->clearAttachments();
```

Comment: Didn't solve the issue. I still get 2 emails

Comment: i think it might be because your using StringAttachment, is your `$pdf` in binary format or base64 format? note that `AddStringAttachment` only support binary format if your `$pdf` is base64 encoded, you will need to `base64_decode()` it first

Comment: `$pdf` is generated from `DomPdf` `$pdf = $dompdf->output();` it's just a string

Comment: There is no such thing as a string, a string is just a managed array of char's and char's are just int8, so any binary data could be shown as a string, but yeah youre using Dompdf->output() then yeah output is binary.